# Having trouble making a scatterplot out of my data in R studio.

Tags: r

[image]

As the title says. Instead of a typical scatterplot with an x and y axis, I get something with a third increment on the right side of the graph. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like line 1 has the column names, this would coerce the data into character and so your plot is like a barchart of character numbers.

Comment: you need header=TRUE in your read.table arguments

Answer (score 3):

In this dataset, there is a mistake in the first row which is supposed to be the row names rather than the first row. R then assumed that your columns are of class Factor.
To solve it use

```
read.table(...,header=TRUE)
```